# Makefile with Multiple Directories/Module Dependency

Tags: makefile, dependencies

If I am creating one project containing many sub-directories and each corresponding to one specific module, like A, B, C, D, E, F and the executable target E1, E2, E3. Each module correspond to one *.a used by the executable target. My Problem is how to generate the dependencies between modules and modules and the dependencies between modules and the executable targets. That is, if E1 use one file of A, then E1 should be dependent on A since I need linke A.a to create E1.
How should I design my Makefile to generate this type of dependency? Thanks and I am new to Makefile.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a rule for E1 so that A.a is a prerequisite of E1?

Comment: Yes, but I hope to generate this rule automatically instead of writing it myself in case that I make mistakes about that dependency. Is that possible? Or I just want to know how to write Makefiles in a large project containing multiple libs and executables, in which the each executable depend on some of the libs. I thought it would prone to make mistakes when writing these dependencies by hand. thanks

Comment: These dependencies can be handled automatically, but it's tricky. What language are you using? And do you have a sensible naming convention (e.g. `A/A.a`)?

Comment: c and c++. Yes the naming convention is A/A.a and all the executable target in same folder or different folders does not matter. Would you tell me how to handle it? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using GNU Make.  You should define a "canned recipe" which encapsulates how you go from libraries to the executable. The recipe should use "automatic variables" so that it is independent on the particular files. Because it is only one recipe, it is debugged once and then can be used without further errors.

You then write rules where you explicitly state the target and prerequisite libraries. Because it is so explicit, it is highly error-proof. Then you use the canned recipe. The recipe will complain if you messed up the prerequisite line.

An example is below.

Typically, you will have other prerequisites besides the libraries.  For example, you should always have the list of the makefiles used. You may also need to ensure the directory of the target is created.  That is why in the recipe below, I used filter.

Please consult the GNU Make manual for all the terms unexplained here.

```
define recipe=
link $@ $(filter %.a, $^)
endef

E1: A.a (other prerequisites)
    $(recipe)
```